# Nodejs not running

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

recently I installed Nodejs on Windows 7 and it was working perfectly. Few days ago it stops running well, for example: if I write "node C:/dir/.../server.js" the console shows: "..." and do nothing.

I have checked the 80 port and it is free, can you please help me?

[image]

Comment: +1 for including a screen-shot. Very clear. :-)

Comment: You're currently in the Node shell trying to execute JavaScript code which isn't JavaScript (`...` means you have a syntax error).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't enter `node<enter>` first. Also, you need quotes. When you've opened cmd, directly type `node "C:\Users\Us Navy\..."`.

Answer (score 3):

When you run the node executable without arguments it opens a repl useful for quick tinkering.

To run a file provide the file as the first argument.